# SkobblerMaps Android: How to create navigation log file

Tags: android, skmaps

I want to simulate a drive using the `SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.FILE`. Is there an easy way to generate one of these files? I see the `Seattle.log` in the demo project, and I could just edit some coordinates and make my own however it would be great to simulate a real drive. Also I am not sure what all of the entries are:

"47.655942 -122.137419, 11.000000, 19.000000, 0.000000, 1380803959889470, 03.10.2013 15:39:19" (what are 11.000000, 19.000000, 0.000000?)

Update: I still do not have a way of doing this and I do not understand some of the values (listed above). The file is `Seattle.log` and it just consists of a bunch of lines like the one above separated by newlines.

Comment: `1380803959889470` looks like milliseconds unix timestamp

Comment: haha you have too much questions on SkobblerMaps

Comment: @CharukaSilva they seem to prefer that questions are asked on here. also they do not have any decent documentation or tutorials

Comment: no worries,  if you can link the demo file may be we can help more

Comment: @CharukaSilva it is called `Seattle.log` and consists of many entries just like the one above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the full SDK documentation here.
https://www.developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/3.0.2/index.html

Yes, you can obtain a logging file with data collected from a real drive. You can use the startLoggingPositions(String filePath, SPositionLoggingType positionLoggingType) and public boolean stopLoggingPositions() from the SKPositionLoggingManager class (com.skobbler.ngx.positioner.logging package) to accomplish that. You will obtain a log file (if the positionLoggingType is set to SK_POSITION_LOGGING_TYPE_LOG) similar to Seattle.log at the specified path.

The values stored in the file are (in this order): Latitude, Longitude, Course, Speed, Accuracy, Timestamp.